# Python Socket 'ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61]'

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, connection

Im writing a Server-Client program with the socket module. At some point the client connects to the server with 'sock.connect((IP, PORT))' but if there is no server listening for a connection the client throws an exception. My question is how do I catch this exception to try again? Maybe with a 5 second pause in between until the server is up to catch the connection.
I have tried:

```
while True:
   try:
      sock.connect((IP, PORT))
   except ConnectionRefusedError:
      time.sleep(5)
```

but another exception is thrown 'OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument'. Should I catch this exception as well?
Is it even possible to catch this exception without ending the program?

Comment: You can't reconnect a TCP socket, even if the prior connection attempt failed. You have to close it and create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The problem was that I tried to use the same socket object to connect again if it has failed. The solution was to just create a new socket with 'sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)'. I don't know if I will get in trouble if I create so many new sockets but it works so far. This code will try to connect 6 times.
Code:

```
timeouts = 5
for i in range(0, timeouts):
   try:
      sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      sock.connect((IP, PORT))
      break
   except socket.error:
      sock.close()
      print(i)
      if i == timeouts-1:
         exit()
      time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: look into connect_ex() it looks like it would solve your problem without having to close the socket [realypython.com exerpt](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/#multi-connection-client)

Comment: It does work the first time connecting and returns 0 when the connection is possible and 61 when it is not possible but when trying to connect again the OSError shows up again with the return value of 22. I think I will keep it the way I had it. Still thanks for your awnser.